# How can I execute a javascript function that is on a web page using VB.NET?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, automation

What I am trying to do is go to a website using a webbrowser, and then simulate a click. I can do this easy enough when the click is on a regular button, not handling javascript. But it seems that the website has a javascript function handling the click that I want to simulate:

```
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'><!-- function setgotopageNR() { if (document.gotopageform.gotopage_reverse.value=='1') { document.gotopageform.page.value=8+1-document.gotopageform.gotopage.value; } else { document.gotopageform.page.value=document.gotopageform.gotopage.value; } } //--></script>
```

I have tried various solutions found through googling, such as WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript, also opening the website in internet explorer and then converting its document to IHTMLDocument2 and getting its parent window as IHTMLWindow2 and then using execScript.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by, "go to a website"?

Comment: thats an interesting question, with an interesting answer?

Comment: Please take the time to re-frame your question to state exactly what you want to accomplish (e.g I want to be able to run javascript in console against a third party website to simulate a click, or I want to be able to register a start-up script when my page loads to simulate a click, or I want to run a third party website in an IFrame and simulate a click from the parent).  Remember to take the time to frame your question well and you will find that you get the answer you need.

Comment: So my question stems from the website "freebooksread.blogspot.com", where you can read books for free online. If you go to "readbookonlinefree.blogspot.com/2011/07/jkgh1hj.html" you see the first Harry Potter book. Every time the user wants to turn a page they click on the right page to go forward, the left to go back. However, as the web address is the same no matter what page you're on, you can't just return to the page you were at. I want to be able to simulate the click to turn the page forward the appropriate number of times to get the user to the page they were on.

Answer (score 0):

Normally one would do `document.getElementById(id).click()`. It should be easy to convert to whatever language you are using to host web browser.

If `click` does not work please post more details on solutions you've already tried and what problems you got.